# How to check if a directory is empty in perl?

Tags: perl

What is a simple way to check whether a directory is empty or not? 
    $directory = "/my_directory"
I just want to check whether $directory is empty, or has any file, or has any file with specific extension, e.g *.txt.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Perl, so this answer is not complete.

```
// Create an integer variable that is initially set to 0.
opendir ( DIR, $dirname )
// Check if opendir failed. Return whatever value you think is appropriate.
while( ($filename = readdir(DIR))){
    // Increment integer variable
}
// Check if integer variable is 0.
```

This will at least get you started.